# quitar logo en WordPress, con código php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, condiciones

Intento dejar el logo solo para la pagina de inicio, en wordpress.
así que entre a header.php y le puse un if a la función wordpress  the_custom_logo();
así queda: `if(): the_custom_logo(); endif;` y no tengo idea que poner en el argumento de if(),supongo que tiene que ser algo que verifique que es la pagina de inicio.

---soy nuevo en WordPress y php. gracia!

Answer (score -1):

baya baya, solo era agregarle al argumento de `if(is_front_page())`
Pero si alguien tiene otras formas de hacer esto, tal ves con css, yo encantado de leerles.